# Best Wishes from a Hiring Firm

Tags: human-resources, hiring

The first time I contacted a hiring firm for a job was in 2015.

They did contact me lately for a job I applied to, but they turned my application down (I opted for a very high salary).

These days, they sent me an SMS in which I received best wishes for a religious occasion.

In my country, such hiring firms don't really contact candidates for such reasons. They do contact "candidates" only when they candidate interests them.

Nothing like that happened before, not even with those I completed the hiring process.

Should I consider this SMS as good sign? Am I a particular/noticeable candidate? or is it a mundane drill?

Comment: Sounds like some recruitment firm has decided to try to lift their profile with an outbound SMS campaign.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "please keep in touch" mean when rejected?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/60067/what-does-please-keep-in-touch-mean-when-rejected)

Comment: They consider you worth spending between 4 and 8 cents on. There's nothing else to tell from this. VTC company-specific.

Answer (score 2):

You may or may not be a viable candidate but if they start resorting to such cold calling measures, I can almost guarantee that, their business is not doing too great. Probably they are out of candidates to market and they are reaching out to ones which at least have some potential. So, in MY OPINION, this is some good news for you. But don't get your hopes up too high. There might be another reason their business may have gone down. Which is their incompetence.

There is no way of telling which scenario is more likely. If you have colleagues or friends who used this company or better some inside person that you befriended, invite them to have drink with you. They might divulge some information.

Comment: This is not cold calling. The business has a relationship already with the OP. It sounds like a simple campaign. Perhaps not a very effective one. It sounds analogous to getting a "happy birthday" greeting message from a company that one mentioned his date of birth to.

Comment: @brandin That constitutes a cold-calling in my book. Sorry, this is my perception. Established relationship here is them to find me a position, not to keep up with my social calendar.